# How to connect to https site with Scrapy via Polipo over TOR?

Tags: python, scrapy, tor

Not entirely sure what the problem is here.

Running Python 2.7.3, and Scrapy 0.16.5

I've created a very simple Scrapy spider to test connecting to my local Polipo proxy so I can send requests out via TOR. Basic code of my spider is as follows:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

class TorSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "tor"
    allowed_domains = ["check.torproject.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://check.torproject.org"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        print response.body
```

For my proxy middleware, I've defined:

```
class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = settings.get('HTTP_PROXY')
```

My HTTP_PROXY in my settings file is defined as `HTTP_PROXY = 'http://localhost:8123'`.

Now, if I change my start URL to http://check.torproject.org, everything works fine, no problems.

If I attempt to run against https://check.torproject.org, I get a 400 Bad Request error every time (I've also tried different https:// sites, and all of them have the same problem):

```
2013-07-23 21:36:18+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.16.5 started (bot: arachnid)
2013-07-23 21:36:18+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2013-07-23 21:36:18+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, RandomUserAgentMiddleware, ProxyMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-07-23 21:36:18+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2013-07-23 21:36:18+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2013-07-23 21:36:18+0100 [tor] INFO: Spider opened
2013-07-23 21:36:18+0100 [tor] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2013-07-23 21:36:18+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2013-07-23 21:36:18+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2013-07-23 21:36:18+0100 [tor] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://check.torproject.org> (failed 1 times): 400 Bad Request
2013-07-23 21:36:18+0100 [tor] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://check.torproject.org> (failed 2 times): 400 Bad Request
2013-07-23 21:36:18+0100 [tor] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET https://check.torproject.org> (failed 3 times): 400 Bad Request
2013-07-23 21:36:18+0100 [tor] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <GET https://check.torproject.org> (referer: None)
2013-07-23 21:36:18+0100 [tor] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

And just to double check that it isn't something wrong with my TOR/Polipo set up, I'm able to run the following curl command in a terminal, and connect fine: `curl --proxy localhost:8123 https://check.torproject.org/`

Any suggestions as to what's wrong here?

Comment: What is your https_proxy set to? HTTP and HTTPS are typically sent over different ports, etc, and will require different proxys.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Surely connecting to an HTTP proxy, which in turn connects to an HTTPS URL, should work fine? Why would I have to connect to an HTTPS proxy to connect to an HTTPS URL? If that was the case, wouldn't the above cURL command fail?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
rq.meta['proxy'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8123'
```

In my case it's works

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if these may help you:

- [How to use scrapy with an internet connection through a proxy with authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176975/how-to-use-scrapy-with-an-internet-connection-through-a-proxy-with-authenticatio)
- http://mahmoud.abdel-fattah.net/2012/04/07/using-scrapy-with-proxies/
- [Enabling HttpProxyMiddleware in scrapyd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945873/enabling-httpproxymiddleware-in-scrapyd)

Comment: Although your links may contain the answers, one of the goals of StackOverflow is to catalog and organize the actual solutions to problems, and not just a link which might break or need additional parsing. If you can summarize the relevant parts in an answer and use the links as references, it would make your answer more acceptable. See [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) for more guidelines.