# How to use scrapy with an internet connection through a proxy with authentication

Tags: python, proxy, web-scraping, scrapy

My internet connection is through a proxy with authentication and when i try to run scraoy library to make the more simple example, for example :

```
scrapy shell http://stackoverflow.com
```

All it's ok until you request something with the XPath selector the response is the next :

```
>>> hxs.select('//title')
[<HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//title' data=u'<title>ERROR: Cache Access Denied</title'>]
```

Or if you try to run any spider created inside a project gave me the following error :

```
C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\test\test>scrapy crawl test
2012-08-11 17:38:02-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.16.5 started (bot: test)
2012-08-11 17:38:02-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetCon
sole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2012-08-11 17:38:02-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAut
hMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, De
faultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpProxyMiddlewa
re, HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2012-08-11 17:38:02-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMi
ddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddle
ware
2012-08-11 17:38:02-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines:
2012-08-11 17:38:02-0400 [test] INFO: Spider opened
2012-08-11 17:38:02-0400 [test] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped
0 items (at 0 items/min)
2012-08-11 17:38:02-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:602
4
2012-08-11 17:38:02-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6081
2012-08-11 17:38:47-0400 [test] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://automation.whatismyi
p.com/n09230945.asp> (failed 1 times): TCP connection timed out: 10060: Se produ
jo un error durante el intento de conexi¾n ya que la parte conectada no respondi
¾ adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la cone
xi¾n establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder..
2012-08-11 17:39:02-0400 [test] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped
0 items (at 0 items/min)
...
2012-08-11 17:39:29-0400 [test] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2012-08-11 17:39:29-0400 [test] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 3,
  'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError': 3,
     'downloader/request_bytes': 732,
     'downloader/request_count': 3,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 11, 21, 39, 29, 908000),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 9,
     'log_count/ERROR': 1,
     'log_count/INFO': 5,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 11, 21, 38, 2, 876000)}
2012-08-11 17:39:29-0400 [test] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

it appears that my proxy its the problem. Please if somebody know a way to use scrapy with a authentication proxy let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scrapy supports proxies by using [HttpProxyMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware):

> This middleware sets the HTTP proxy to use for requests, by setting
>   the proxy meta value to Request objects. Like the Python standard
>   library modules urllib and urllib2, it obeys the following environment
>   variables:
>
> - http_proxy
> - https_proxy
> - no_proxy

Also see:

- [Using Scrapy with proxies](http://mahmoud.abdel-fattah.net/2012/04/07/using-scrapy-with-proxies/)
- [Enabling HttpProxyMiddleware in scrapyd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945873/enabling-httpproxymiddleware-in-scrapyd)

Comment: The thing is that the first link does not work for me I don't know why and the second already read and I don't know hot to set the http_proxy variable, If you help me

Comment: Have you set `http_proxy` or `https_proxy` environment variable?

Comment: yes man, the problem is fixed thanks. The link http://mahmoud.abdel-fattah.net/2012/04/07/using-scrapy-with-proxies/ was very usefull.

Comment: @alecxe can I set the https_proxy per request?

Comment: If anyone is looking for the first link wbwm has it: `https://web.archive.org/web/*/mahmoud.abdel-fattah.net/2012/04/07/using-scrapy-with-proxies/`

Comment: @Sir alecxe, as I'm very new to `scrapy`, I'm little behind understanding where to put `middlewares.py` file, If I try to follow the first link you have provided in which there is a instruction `Create a new file called “middlewares.py” and save it in your scrapy project and add---`. However, the thing is I've already a file named `middlewares.py` which has been created by default. So should I replace it with the suggested one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Repeating the answer by **Mahmoud M. Abdel-Fattah**, because the page is not available now. Credit goes to him, however, I made slight modifications.

If `middlewares.py` already exist, add the following code into it.

```
class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    # overwrite process request
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        # Set the location of the proxy
        request.meta['proxy'] = "http://YOUR_PROXY_IP:PORT"

        # Use the following lines if your proxy requires authentication
        proxy_user_pass = "USERNAME:PASSWORD"
        # setup basic authentication for the proxy
        encoded_user_pass = base64.encodestring(proxy_user_pass.encode())
        #encoded_user_pass = base64.encodestring(proxy_user_pass)
        request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + \
            str(encoded_user_pass)
```

In settings.py file, add the following code

```
    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'project_name.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 100,
}
```

This should work by setting `http_proxy`. However, In my case, I'm trying to access a URL with HTTPS protocol, need to set `https_proxy` which I'm still investigating. Any lead on that will be of great help.