# Proxy authentication in scrapy request

Tags: python, authentication, proxy, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl a website with scrapy using the request object. I connect to the internet through a proxy that requires authentication, and this authentication prevents me from crawling the website:
`DEBUG: Crawled (400) <GET http://auth4/robots.txt> (referer: None)`

How can I authenticate in the proxy or skip it to reach the website?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the User Agent. Try to set the User Agent to `'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0'`
 in the `settings.py`

Edit: check this out [How to use scrapy with an internet connection through a proxy with authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176975/how-to-use-scrapy-with-an-internet-connection-through-a-proxy-with-authenticatio?rq=1)